# Как загрузить свою программу на джейлбрейкнутый айфон?

Tags: xcode, iphone, сборка

Нет желания платить 99$ ради программы разработчиков Apple. 
У меня есть джейл-брейкнутый iphone и приложение написанное в Xcode.

1. Возможно ли загрузить своё приложение на джейл-брейкнутый айфон с Xcode?
2. Как это сделать?
3. Есть ли в этом занятии подводные камни?

**Update**:

Всё это получилось у меня. Я использовал `xcode 7.3` и `ios 7.0`. 
Оказалось довольно просто.

1. Подключаете `iphone` к `xcode`.
2. В строке "симуляторы" выставляете ваш девайс. (кнопка слева вверху, чуть правее `run`)
3. Нажимаете `run`
4. Вам, вероятно, выкинет что-то вроде "введите ваш `apple id`".
5. Вводите `Apple id` (его регистрация бесплатна в отличие от `app developer program`).
6. Возможна ошибка устройства по умолчанию. Чтобы её не случилось в графе deployment target выберите операционную систему соответствующие вашей. (В моём случае был ios 7.0 и я его и выбрал).[image: Скриншот]

   7. Ну а далее - всё запускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам не пробовал но предпложу:

0) вам не надо платить 99$, чтоб загрузить программу на iphone (теперь платить надо только за публикацию приложения в аппстор)

1) да можно

2) так же, как и на обычный: подключить телефон к маку, выбрать его из дропдауна в xcode, command+r (либо run из меню)

3) подводных камней нет

Comment: ох, у меня ios 7.0.6, а бесплатный тестинг работает, по моим данным (http://appleinsider.ru/app-store/kak-ustanovit-prilozhenie-v-obxod-app-store.html) на последней версии xcode и последней версии ios.

Comment: да вы правы. только 9 и выше. остальные пункты ответа вроде бы из за этого не меняются

Comment: то есть вы хотите сказать что можно для тестирования своих ios приложений использовать ios<8, и не платя эпплу? 
Может быть вы дадите ссылку на подробную инструкцию, как это делается?

Comment: нет, я хочу сказать, что не смотря на то, что у вас не получится залить на не джейлбрейк айфон, для джейлбрейка остальные пункты те же

Comment: Да, вы были почти во всём правы, кроме того, что на ios 7 тоже всё запускается (если xcode 7.3). Так что спасибо.